# Doing an API capstone project, cannot retrieve value from text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, forms

First post here.

(forgive the CSS here, it's a work in progress)

Here is my repl-it: https://repl.it/@Johnmexico/BlandElegantOrigin-1

I'll try and summarize as best as I can. I declared the value of the text input on line 7 of the JS file, and I attempted to plug it in my AJAX, as well as in my fetchAPIList function in line 22.

JS:

```
const artistName = $('.query').val();

function getDataFromApiSongs(endpoint, callback) {
  $.ajax({
      data: Object.assign(
          { 
            apikey: APIKey, 
            format: 'json' 
          }, 
          `q_artist=${artistName}`
      ), 
      contentType: 'application/json', 
      type: "GET", 
      url: MusicAPI + endpoint
  })
  .done(callback);
}

function fetchAPIList(){
    getDataFromApiSongs(`track.search?q_artist=${artistName}&page_size=10&page=1&s_track_rating=desc`, (response) =>{...
```

HTML:

```
        <fieldset>
            <form action=# role="form" onsubmit="fetchAPIList()">
                <label for="search-musixmatch" id="label">Find Songs by Artist</label>
                <input class="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for Artist">
                <input class="submit-button" type="submit">

            </form>

        </fieldset>
```

Now, if I hard-code it and artist such as "drake" instead of ${artistName}, I get exactly what I'm looking for, the top 10 Drake songs at the moment. If I enter an artist and submit with my original code (which just returns the top 10 songs in the entire database, disregarding any parameters.

So my question is, how do I properly put the value from the input and use it to fetch the info from the API? (e.g. "2pac" or any other artist) Because apparently, what I am doing right now is not the correct way to do it.

PS, you must use an allow CORS extension in the browser, but I'm sure many of you guys already have such plug-in.

Thank you,
Ricardo.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that

```
const artistName = $('.query').val();
```

runs when your page first loads. Therefore you assign to `artistName` the value of whatever was in the "query" textbox at that moment. The variable does not then get updated when you type a new value. What you need to be doing is asking what the value of the box is at the moment when your fetchAPIList() function runs, and then using that in your URL.

A secondary problem is that you run the fetchAPIList() function when the form is submitted...but you don't prevent the default behaviour of the form, which is to do a traditional full-page postback to the server.

Putting those two things together, and combined with the fact you use jQuery, and that it's generally considered better practice to use unobtrusive event handlers (i.e. event handlers declared in the main script, rather than embedded in the HTML), we can rearrange the code like this:

HTML (the change here is that the form no longer has "onsubmit", but it does have an "id" to identify it):

```
<fieldset>
        <form action=# role="form" id="searchForm">
            <label for="search-musixmatch" id="label">Find Songs by Artist</label>
            <input class="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for Artist">
            <input class="submit-button" type="submit">

        </form>
</fieldset>
```

JS (changed getAPIList function to unobtrusive event handler, removed un-used watchSubmit and displaySongData functions, redefined getDataFromApiSongs function to accept latest artistName value):

```
const MusicAPI = "https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/";
const APIKey= "a2870731fab086760a6e7e1a767ceb86";

function getDataFromApiSongs(endpoint, artistName, callback) {
  $.ajax({
      data: Object.assign({ 
          apikey: APIKey, 
          format: 'json' }, `q_artist=${artistName}`), 
      contentType: 'application/json', 
      type: "GET", 
      url: MusicAPI + endpoint}).done(callback);
}

//unobtrusive "submit" event handler written using jQuery syntax
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent default postback behaviour
  var artistName = $(".query").val();
      getDataFromApiSongs(`track.search?q_artist=${artistName}&page_size=10&page=1&s_track_rating=desc`, artistName, (response) =>{
      const message = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(message.body)
        const { message:{ body: {track_list = []}}} = message;
        console.log(track_list);
        let songDOM = ''
        track_list.map((item) => {
            const {track:{ track_name,artist_name, album_name }} = item;
            songDOM += `<li><b>Title</b>: "${track_name}" by ${artist_name}, <i>${album_name}</i>`;
        });
        let songsList = document.getElementById('songsList')
        songsList.innerHTML = songDOM;
        $(".query").val("");
    });
});
```

Updated repl: https://repl.it/repls/GoodnaturedNoisyApplication